# ASP.net vb code behinddeployed compiling error

Tags: asp.net, compilation

Background: I am not an ASP developer, I understand OOP processes and can program in Javascript, Actionscript, and am learning PHP. I used to know VB.net in a limited fashion.

I am forced(by existing platform configuration) to develop a small .aspx page, i have been reading many tutorials, but am unable to get my page below to work. The best i can get is an 500 error message but no details are listed even though detailed error messages is configured. I dont have access to Visual Studios for this an am using Dreamweaver to develop.

I'm attempting to use the compiling method that compiles when the page is first viewed instead of precompiling

I cant seem to get this basic "hello world" type page to work. What am i doing wrong?

*Edited code to represent changes made*
**CurrentNews.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"  Src="/Scripts/CurrentNews.aspx.vb" Inherits="NewsFunctionality" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/NewsLayoutOne.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="OuterDiv" runat="server">
        <img id="NewsImage" src="Images/DefaultNews1.png" >
        <div id="NewsBody" runat="server">Original Text</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CurrentNews.aspc.vb**

```
' VB Document
```

Class NewsFunctionality
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    'On load event for the page linked to this class file
   protected sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
       NewsBody.InnerHTML = "

Dynamic Text Generated.

"
    End Sub

End Class

Comment: As it turned out my webserver wasn't set up correctly, so IT rebuilt it and now its working, or at least throwing errors that contain details. Thank you for the assistance though

Comment: I'm now getting the following error and no matter what i try it wont go away.
Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'NewsBody' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I replaced the asp:TestBox with just writing the html into a div element and even though i added runat="server" to the div and access the div using divID.InnerHTML i still get the error

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance, i would say at minimum your code would not do what you expect.  You are putting "`<P>Dynamic Text Generated</P>`" to be rendered in an input field.

Other than that though im not seeing anything that obviously would not work.  What is the behavior you see?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Page_Load` sub should declared protected. The relation between aspx page and aspx.vb class is somehow like inheritance.